# SQL Server : check constraint to check customers are over 18

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, constraints

I am using SQL Server Management Studio and would like to create a table that when dates are entered in to the table, it checks that someone is over 18.

I have got as far as:

```
CREATE TABLE tCustomer
(
    FirstName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    DateOfBirth DATE CHECK (DateOfBirth < GETDATE())
);
```

I know this is currently wrong as all it is doing is checking that the `DateOfBirth` is less than the current time. But I can't quite seem to find what I am looking for.

If it is too complex for create table, maybe some sort of trigger? I do not really want to use a stored procedure.

Your help would be appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This condition is invalid in a check constraint because it is non-deterministic. If the clock is turned back suddenly rows that were valid could now become invalid. The constraint would retroactively be invalidated.

You should probably move this check to the application.

Comment: I was going to use C# to do the check, but I also wanted some kind of constraint in the database.

Comment: Understandable, yet a) not easily possible and b) not appropriate. Database constraints should validate the data independently of any environment such as time. If you insist, use a trigger.